# Packet sniffer for router in windows

Tags: router, sniffing

Is there a packet analyzer for windows for analyzing packets that passes through the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Wireshark, you would also need a hub.

Hook the router to the hub and have everyone else plugged into the hub as well.

Then on your windows machine open up Wireshark and capture the traffic.

You should see all traffic destined for the router, as well as other clients.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a new firmware for the router, which lets you low-level access to ... pretty much everything. And then, analyze whatever you want, however you want. (Openwrt?)

(But this already makes the question off-topic.)